# INTENT.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE not saving file to custom location Uri

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created an app like this.
It has a Button , on the click of button the video capture starts.

now I have a code like this for it:-

```
public class VideoCaptureComponentActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    VideoView vv;
    ImageButton ib;
    TextView tv;
    Intent i;
    final static int cameraData=0;
    File path = null;
    Uri myVideo;

    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        vv= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvVideoCapture);
        ib=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFilePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnVideo:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();  // create a file to save the video
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); // set the video image quality to high

                // start the Video Capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                break;
        }

    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
     if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
     {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                myVideo= data.getData();
                tv.setText(myVideo.toString());
                vv.setVideoURI(myVideo);
                vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                vv.requestFocus();
                vv.start(); 
            }           
    }
}


/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri()
{
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_CAPTURED" + ".mp4");
   return mediaFile;
}


}
```

now after I m capturing the video the application is crashing.

```
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.optimus.mobile.survey/com.optimus.mobile.survey.VideoCaptureComponentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3712)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3754)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2162)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at com.optimus.mobile.survey.VideoCaptureComponentActivity.onActivityResult(VideoCaptureComponentActivity.java:82)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3708)
07-06 17:12:09.447: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     ... 11 more
```

basically the problem is that that
in the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
```

here it is not saving the file to location set , I dont know whats the problem .
I took this code from this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Did you add the permition to write to external storage? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Please provide the line 82 of your code !!!

Comment: Yes I provided the line Write External Storage permission

Comment: the line 82 of your code plz!!!

Comment: the line 82 of my code would be in function on Activity Result posted in my above code.!!

Comment: are you testing on an emulator or  what?

Comment: there's a problem in this am trying to make the same thing , when adding fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);   . I think the documentation is not correct my app very very very ehn adding this lines , If i removed it the performance great and the app works well . need more help :(

Comment: @AdityaPratap i agree with you man. i'm doing same thing with audio and video and not seeing any video at custom location.But when same thing applied to simple camera and it worked!!! So did u find any solution to this weird issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No if you are passing `Uri` for saving Image or Video with `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);` then you always receive `data.getData();` in `onActivityResult` as `NULL`. so use `Uri` of image or Video passed with intent as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
     if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
     {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
              //  myVideo= data.getData();
                tv.setText("Video"); 
                vv.setVideoURI(fileUri);//set Uri here which you passed with Intent
                vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                vv.requestFocus();
                vv.start(); 
            }           
    }
}
```

Comment: this wont solve the problem still showing the same error , maybe you could help me  that how can i save the video file captured through my video activity to custom location.

Comment: first make sure video is created or not on SD CARD?

Answer (score 2):

```
private static String FILE_NAM1  = "video_one";

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == VIDEO_ACTIVITY) {
        Uri videoFileUri = data.getData();
        String outputfile = getFilesDir() + File.separator+FILE_NAM1+"_tmp.mp4";

        try {
            InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoFileUri);
            MainActivity.createFileFromInputStream(in, outputfile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("saved uri is "+videoFileUri.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), VideoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("video_uri",videoFileUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private static File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {

   try{
      File f = new File(fileName);
      f.setWritable(true, false);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("error in creating a file");
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
}
```

remove intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  from the intent

Comment: `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`. Relying on third-party apps to do undocumented things is not a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for rec and save video:

```
private String name_vid; 
private static int REC_VIDEO = 1;
public void rec_vid(View v) {
    //set name & path to vid
    name_vid = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/videos/myvid.mp4";
    //check if folder exists, else, create it
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/videos/");
    if (!path.exists())
    path.mkdirs();
    //create the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    int code = REC_VIDEO;
    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(name_vid));
    //Add extra to save video
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(intent, code);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REC_VIDEO) {
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            //create a MediaScanner to save the vid into the indicate path
            new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                private MediaScannerConnection msc = null;
                {
                    msc = new MediaScannerConnection(
                            getApplicationContext(), this);
                    msc.connect();
                }

                public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                    msc.scanFile(name_vid, null);
                }

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    msc.disconnect();

                }
            };
            Toast.makeText(this,"Video saved succesfull",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Remember that you have to set the permission uses in he manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This code stored a video is a given path. But the stored video is not playing. it showing the "error sorry this video cannot be played" in a alertdialogbox any help

Comment: You should check 2 things, android devices records video in mp4, but others rec in 3gp, try changing this format into the name_vid.. 

when u set the videopath at the VideoView it don't have to get the "mnt/" path, so, what I do is remove this part of the name:vid variable, check:

`VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);`
`//cut the "mnt/" in the video_name`
`vv.setVideoPath(name_vid.substring(4, name_vid.length()));`
`//create the media controllers`
`vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));`
`//start to play the vid`
`vv.start();`

Comment: Add this into the onActivityResult, after the Toast: Video saved succesfull

Comment: but i went to sd card storage manually where the video is stored and try to play the video that time it is not playing

Comment: For me this creates a file of size 0.