# How to record low quality video in mp4 format in android?

Tags: android

I am recording a low quality video from camera and uploading it to server. The issue is that the video which is recorded comes in 3gp format. Even if i give EXTRA_OUTPUT flag with a mp4 extension path, still it records in 3gp.

Actually, on iOS device, this 3gp video is not playing and i don't want to convert it to mp4 using ffmpeg because it has a overhead and it will take time to convert.

This is the code i am using :-

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            try {
                Uri videoUriFromCamera = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUriFromCamera);
                if (videoSize != -1)
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, videoSize);
                if (videoDuration != -1)
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, videoDuration);

                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_REQUEST_VIDEO_FROM_CAMERA);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(VideoPickActivity.this, "SD-Card not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Is there any way or flag that i can record low quality videos in mp4 format or any other format using the default camera intent ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

First, there is no documented extra on `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` for stating a particular video container format (e.g., MP4). The best approach for attempting to ask that would be to pass a `Uri` for a file, where the file extension is `.mp4`, but even that is just a hope.

Second, there are thousands of camera apps that advertise support for `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, including hundreds of camera apps that are preinstalled. None have to honor any of your extras. None have to pay attention to file extensions to make a choice of video container format.

If you want that degree of control over the video recording, record the video yourself, such as by using `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: "but even that is just a hope" - I wonder if these answers are in any way suitable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883934/how-to-set-the-output-of-a-file-as-mp4-using-intent-to-a-camera-with-a-action-of , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361597/intent-action-video-capture-not-saving-file-to-custom-location-uri

Comment: @DanielWilson: Those are "pass a Uri for a file, where the file extension is .mp4". There is no requirement that any app pay attention to that file extension.

Comment: Should have been more specific after looking more closely. How do you feel about @PKV 's answer in that second link? That's the one that seems reasonable to me. (S)he seems to create an MP4 from the file stream of data in the response: *InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())*, which I'm hoping is quite different to asking for an mp4 in the intent via MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Comment: @DanielWilson: That answer is worse, insofar as [`ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), so few camera apps will work with that code. It also would not address the problem. You are invoking a third-party camera app. That app's developers can do whatever they want. This includes *not actually recording a video*, let alone not recording it in your desired format. If you need the video to be recorded in a particular format, record it yourself.

Comment: Okay well damn. I understand 3rd party intents can be flaky and we can't guarantee a video but I figured I'd at least be able to convert a video to Mp4 *most of the time* if I did get one. My options seem to be to use the damn media recorder (which I'm doing at the moment but it's littered with strange device specific problems), or maybe convert the file on our server. I'll do a little more research, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to get a bit deeper into the mechanics of using the camera:
Create a MediaRecorder, and set up a CamcorderProfile, which you can set up with some finesse.

```
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mRec = new MediaRecorder();
    mRec.setCamera(mCamera);
    mRec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    mProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
    mRec.setProfile(mProfile);
```