# How to set the output of a file as mp4 using intent to a camera with a action of ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, camera, mp4

when I am using my native app camera to take video, the output file have 3gp extension. I need to intent to camera with ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent action which will produce a file that has a mp4 file extension. how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and try dis code:

```
intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);    
   fileUri = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video in specific folder (this works for video only)
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high

    // start the Video Capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED_NEXUS);
```

This will be called once the capture is completed

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED_NEXUS:
    this.videoFromCamera(resultCode, data);
    break;

default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

private void videoFromCamera(int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    if(fileUri != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video saved to:\n" + fileUri);
        Log.d(TAG, "Video path:\n" + fileUri.getPath());
        Log.d(TAG, "Video name:\n" + getName(fileUri)); 
// use uri.getLastPathSegment() if store in folder
//use the file Uri.
    }
}
```

Get the output Media file uri with the following Method

```
public Uri getOutputMediaFile(int type)
    {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted

        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
            // this works for Android 2.2 and above
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "SMW_VIDEO");

            // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
            // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
           if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This will save the captured video in pure MP4 format.

Comment: The video output is in mp4 video format but its mime type is 3gpp. So its not a pure mp4 video

Comment: So the video is not playable at ios devices using default player

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following code before start the intent :

```
videoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fname_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4"));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
```

Comment: is the file will be a real mp4 video? or just the file extension?

Comment: This does not seem to be working with the default camera app on the LG G3. The file is still a 3gp file, only the file extension changes.

Comment: @Waboodoo did you ever find a solution to this. I have the same issue.  Certain phones ignore any file path you give it and record in 3gp when you use the camera capture intent.

Comment: @horsejockey Unfortunately not, and I did not continue working on this problem. My conclusion would be that we simply have no control over what type of video the camera returns us, so if we want to enforce a certain type we have to transcode the video ourselves and/or implement our own video recorder.

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this? I'm having the same conundrum on an LG G8s. The `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent always returns a 240x320px 3GP video with extremely bad quality.