# How to record video in .mp4 format using intents

Tags: android

I use `Intent MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` video recording method. 
By default, the recorded video is stored as a .3gp file. I want to record and store the video as a .mp4 file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the output of a file as mp4 using intent to a camera with a action of ACTION\_VIDEO\_CAPTURE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883934/how-to-set-the-output-of-a-file-as-mp4-using-intent-to-a-camera-with-a-action-of)

Comment: only extension is changed to .mp4 but video is captured in .3gp format

Answer (score -1):

When you set (EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY = 1) then file save as mp4 and when you set (EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY =0) then file save as 3gp and suitable for mms.
 [EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY)

You can  test it by your phone. get a video by camera and see extension on detail file and get a video by mms and see detail of thatand you can see the extension is 3gp.

Comment: You're may right on some handsets. I just wonder where you know the value 0 equals to 3gp and the same to mp4? Where did you get that? I tried it now and it did as you said but the video isn't so fluently. I'm about to custom one for myself not use the system camera.